# PHP href con condicional

Tags: php

Necesito crear un código para galería de imágenes con un vínculo condicional de href. Lo he intentado, pero como es un archivo php se enreda todo.

```php
//defino un directorio    
$pathA = "images/"; 

//creo un array    
$ArrayA=Array();

//abro función glob para incluir imágenes en array    
foreach(glob($pathA . '*.jpg') as $imageA) {
    $ArrayA[]=$imageA;
}

//inicio bucle
for($n = 1; $n <= count($ArrayA); $n++):

    //href dada una imagen se va a la misma
    //sino se va a la imagen anterior   
    echo '<a href= "'if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[5]) { echo $miArray[5] } else if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[$n-1]) { echo $miArray[$i-1] }'">' .

    //etiqueta img src dentro de etiqueta href para mostrar imágenes  
    '<img src= "' . $miArray[$i] . '">' . '</a>' .

    '</a>';


endfor;
```

El error es:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';'
>   in C:...php on line 26

La línea 26 es:

```
echo '<a href= "'if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[5]) { echo $miArray[5] } else if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[$n-1]) { echo $miArray[$i-1] }'">' .
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás ejecutando mal tanto el `if` como los `echo` dentro del mismo, no puedes hacer un `echo` dentro de otro, por lo tanto tienes que cerrar el `tag` de `php` para renderizar el HTML como tal y ya adentro del elemento `<a>` puedes proceder a hacer el condicional, te dejo aquí tu mismo código corregido:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>galeria</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$pathA = "images/";

//creo un array
$ArrayA=Array();

foreach(glob($pathA . '*.jpg') as $imageA) {
    $ArrayA[]=$imageA;
}

//inicio bucle
for($n = 1; $n <= count($ArrayA); $n++):
?>

<a href="<?php if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[5]) { echo $miArray[5]; } else if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[$n-1]) { echo $miArray[$i-1]; } ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $miArray[$i]; ?>">
</a>

<?php
endfor;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo cambiaría la línea 26 dejando el código así:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>galeria</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//defino un directorio    
$pathA = "images/"; 

//creo un array    
$ArrayA=Array();

//abro función glob para incluir imágenes en array    
foreach(glob($pathA . '*.jpg') as $imageA) {
$ArrayA[]=$imageA;
}

//inicio bucle
for($n = 1; $n <= count($ArrayA); $n++):

//href dada una imagen se va a la misma
//sino se va a la imagen anterior   
$href = ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[5]) ? $miArray[5] : (($miArray[$i] == $miArray[$n-1]) ? $miArray[$i-1] : "");
echo '<a href= "'.$href.'">' .

//etiqueta img src dentro de etiqueta href para mostrar imágenes  
'<img src= "' . $miArray[$i] . '">' . '</a>' .

'</a>';


endfor;    
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu código por el siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>galeria</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//defino un directorio    
$pathA = "images/"; 

//creo un array    
$ArrayA=Array();

//abro función glob para incluir imágenes en array    
foreach(glob($pathA . '*.jpg') as $imageA) {
$ArrayA[]=$imageA;
}

//inicio bucle
for($n = 1; $n <= count($ArrayA); $n++):
?> 
//href dada una imagen se va a la misma
//sino se va a la imagen anterior   
<a href= "<?php if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[5]) { echo $miArray[5]; } else if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[$n-1]) { echo $miArray[$i-1]; } ?>">

//etiqueta img src dentro de etiqueta href para mostrar imágenes  
<img src= "<?php $miArray[$i] ?>"></a>

</a>   
<?php
endfor;    
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahora me queda claro. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera, evita poner condiciones y otros bloques de código dentro de los valores de un atributo de html.

```
<?php
    //defino un directorio    
    $pathA = "images/"; 

    //creo un array    
    $ArrayA=Array();

    //abro función glob para incluir imágenes en array    
    foreach(glob($pathA . '*.jpg') as $imageA) {
    $ArrayA[]=$imageA;
    }

    //inicio ciclo
    for($n = 1; $n <= count($ArrayA); $n++){

    //href dada una imagen se va a la misma
    //sino se va a la imagen anterior 

    if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[5]) {
        $enlace = $miArray[5];
    }elseif($miArray[$i] == $miArray[$n-1]){
        $enlace = $miArray[$i-1];
    }

    ?>

    <a href="<?=$enlace?>"> 
       <img src="<?=$miArray[$i]?>">
    </a>

    <?php  
    }    
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Segun el código que has añadido, yo lo pondria asi:

**ANTES**

```
//defino un directorio    
$pathA = "images/"; 

//creo un array    
$ArrayA=Array();

//abro función glob para incluir imágenes en array    
foreach(glob($pathA . '*.jpg') as $imageA) {
    $ArrayA[]=$imageA;
}

//inicio bucle
for($n = 1; $n <= count($ArrayA); $n++):

    //href dada una imagen se va a la misma
    //sino se va a la imagen anterior   
    echo '<a href= "'if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[5]) { echo $miArray[5] } else if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[$n-1]) { echo $miArray[$i-1] }'">' .

    //etiqueta img src dentro de etiqueta href para mostrar imágenes  
    '<img src= "' . $miArray[$i] . '">' . '</a>' .

    '</a>';


endfor;
```

**AHORA**

```
//defino un directorio    
$pathA = "images/"; 

//creo un array    
$ArrayA = Array();

//abro función glob para incluir imágenes en array    
foreach(glob($pathA . '*.jpg') as $imageA) {
    $ArrayA[] = $imageA;
}

//inicio bucle
for($n = 1; $n <= count($ArrayA); $n++):

    //href dada una imagen se va a la misma
    //sino se va a la imagen anterior   
    if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[5]) {
        echo '<a href= "' . $miArray[5] . '">';
    } 
    else if ($miArray[$i] == $miArray[$n-1]) { 
        echo '<a href= "' . $miArray[$i-1] . '">';
    }
    //etiqueta img src dentro de etiqueta href para mostrar imágenes  
    echo '<img src= "' . $miArray[$i] . '"></a>';

endfor;
```